# Maximum sum of k numbers if elements are picked only from front or rear end

Tags: dynamic-programming

Find maximum sum of k numbers of an integer array

allowed operation only from front end or rear end.

## case 1

```
k = 2
{1,2,3,6}
possible move (1,2), (1,6),(6,3),(6,1)
max sum = 9// for move (1,2) after removal of 1 the only choice is 2 and 6
```

## case 2

```
k = 2
{100,1,200,2} 
o/p = max sum = 202
```

## case 3

```
k = 2
{100,1,200,2} 
o/p => max sum = 100
```

Comment: I'm confused. What is your question?

Comment: @dddJewelsbbb find the maximum sum of k numbers

Comment: So, to clarify, you want the maximum sum of k numbers, with the restriction that the k numbers can only be at the front or end of the numbers that have not yet been selected?

Comment: @dddJewelsbbb, sorry for the confusion caused

Comment: No worries! I'm just trying to help you get this solved. It's an interesting problem, and I feel if it's explained in the question in more detail you will have a better chance of having someone help you find a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take `i` elements from front, you need to take `k-i` elements from back and sum over them. Goal is to find such an `0<=i<=k` that maximizes the sum.

So, naive O(K^2) solution can be:

```
arr = [100,1,200,2]
k = 2
n = len(arr)

total = 0
for i in range(k+1): #i can be 0..k inclusive
    for j in range(i): #take 'i' elements from front 
        total += arr[j]
    for j in range(k-i): #take 'k-i' elements from back
        total += arr[n-1-j]
    print(i,total)
```

with just a little modification, it can be turned O(K). Notice once sum for `i==0` is computed, we just need to add 100 and subtract 200 in this current example to get `total` for `i==1`. So:

```
for i in range(k+1):
    if i>0:
        total += (arr[i-1] - arr[n-k-1+i])
        print(i,total)
        continue
    for j in range(i):
        total += arr[j]
    for j in range(k-i):
        total += arr[n-1-j]
```

when run, it prints the sum (i.e `total` here), if `i` elements are taken from front:

```
0 202
1 102
2 101
```

Comment: i from front, k-i from back -  so simple and straight logic, and i was trying to solve it using dp, top-down ! feel so novice...